# pymongo: "OperationFailure: database error: error querying server"

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

We're occasionally getting the following error when doing queries:

```
OperationFailure: database error: error querying server
```

There is no specific query causing this, and when repeating the process things work. Has anybody else seen this error?

Our setup is a cluster of Ubuntu VMs on Amazon EC2, we're using Python 2.7.3 and pymongo v2.3. We're also using Mongoengine, however we still get this exception from non-Mongoengine code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To those discovering this question:

We were never able to fully diagnose the problem with this, our hunch is that the database connection tends to fail every once in a while for whatever reason. From our research into distributed computing, this is a common problem and needs to be handled explicitly.

In the end, we adapted our system to become robust to DB connection failures by catching `OperationFailure` exceptions along with similar ones and re-establishing the database connection. This resolved the problem along with a number of similar ones we were having.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the query failed on the server - to diagnose you'd need to check the server logs.